# Mobius strip-an intuition

Tags: differential-geometry, real-numbers, equivalence-relations, quotient-spaces, mobius-band

I do not follow how in the snippet below in the example 7.3 the space we are
taking the quotient of is the whole of
$[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}$?
I mean, the diameter of the Mobius strip is **bounded**, but $\mathbb{R}$ is not.
[image]

Comment: The definition you cite is for the *open* Möbius strip, which, according to this author, is not bounded.  Note that "the" Möbius strip may be defined differently by different authors.

Comment: try to do the same with $[0,1]\times(0,1)$

Comment: @MarcoLecci Why have you used the open interval $\times (0,1)$ instead of the closed one?

Comment: Because the definition is for the open strip Möbius.

Comment: @MarcoLecci Yes. And in the l.h.s. of Fig 7.1 is it open in the direction of $x$ axis or of $y$ axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

This is $[0,1]\times (0,1)$ and if you identify $(0,t)$ with $(1,1-t)$ you will obtain the open strip Mobius because points on the dashed lines are not in the square.

Answer (score 0):

Both the Möbius strip and the vector bundle are defined as topological spaces, not as metric spaces, so the notion of "bounded" doesn't apply to them. The real line is, as you said, unbounded, **provided** you use the usual metric $|x-y|$; the same topological space admits other metrics, for example 
$$
\frac{|x-y|}{1+|x-y|},
$$
that are not bounded.